# Audio Output for RPi 3 Mobel+

Tags: audio, output

Very simple question.

If I do this:

Navigate to your screen.
Select "Manage Screen".
Select "Advanced".
Set "Audio Output" to "3.5mm jack".
Press "Save".

Would I be able to listen to music via USB mono powered speakers (no HDMI connection, just USB) with no jack included and also with headphones with it plugged into the jack socket?

I want it so I can do both. It's for the phoniebox.de

Or if there is another way and I can't do it from that, let me know.

Comment: "USB mono powered speakers" - is this a USB audio device, or is it a speaker that connects some other way but simply powered by USB (as the name suggests)

Comment: @Mark, Ah, let me see.  Me too has your hardware config: (1) HDMI mon has no speaker, (2)  3.5mm jack connected to AC200V powered stereo speakers. (3) USB hub connected to USB sound card which is in turn connected to (a) microphone (red) , (b) stereo speakers (green).  I use VLC to listen/watch music/video.  For the GUI desktop top right loudspeaker icon, I always right click and found/select the default HDMI selected.  For VLC my audio device is always set to  default.  I don't use terminal mode raspi-config, which I know > advanced option > audio output device always select option (0) auto.

Comment: I am using Rpi4B buster release 2019sep26.  Earlier versions seemed buggy (see sep26 release notes). / to continue, ...